# Database table design for a customized scenario

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, database-schema, lookup-tables

I am trying to design a database that will store one (or more) meal plans for different people.  There are 2 different scenarios in this question.

First Scenario:

(Please refer to image)[image]

There are 4 tables: PERSON, MEALPLAN, MEALPLAN_FOOD, and FOOD.  The PERSON table stores basic information for each individual owning a meal plan.  The MEALPLAN table will keep track of each meal plan (diet).  The FOOD table is table of different foods (e.g. egg, spinach, sweet potato, oatmeal, etc.) and stores the protein/carb/fat/calorie information for each 'quantity unit' (e.g. 1 cup) for each food item.  The MEALPLAN_FOOD table serves as the lookup/associative table for MEALPLAN and FOOD.

I believe that I have these tables set up correctly.  Each person has one (or more) meal plans.  Each meal plan consists of one (or more) foods/qty.  My  question comes in the next scenario.

Second Scenario:

(Please refer to image)[image]

The first scenario is limited in the fact that it only stores a list of food items per meal plan.  In the second scenario, we would like to incorporate additional tables so that the meal plans can be broken down and stored by meal.  Each person will one (or more) meal plans with between 1 and 4 meals per meal plan (meal plans may consists of only 2 or 3 meals).  In order to accomplish this, the first scenario's MEALPLAN_FOOD lookup/associative table was replaced with 2 lookup/associative tables (MEALPLAN_M<#> and M<#>_FOOD) and a meal table (M1 for meal 1, M2, M3, and M4).

Question:  Assuming that the design of the first scenario is correct, is the design of the second scenario correct in accomplishing the additional functionality?  Is this design correct in additional lookup tables in order to allow for the storage of food items per meal per meal plan per person?  Or, is there a better way/design for accomplishing this task?

Thank you!

Comment: Any time that you find yourself putting a number in either a table name or a column name (with the exception of `address_line_1` and `address_line_2` for a street address) you should get a big red flag that you're doing something wrong.

Comment: @TomH, understood, thank you for the information.  I will use it moving forward.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally not a good idea to have a table per entity (i.e. a table per mealplan/meal of the day).  Instead, alter your original design - add another column on the `MEALPLAN` table that foreign keys to a new table called `MEALOFDAY`.  That way, you can add or remove meals of the day (allow a user to have 6 or 10 meals per day), and you can allow a meal plan to be shared between multiple meals if you add another many to many table for `MEALPLAN_MEALOFDAY`.

Your new table structure for MEALPLAN and MEALOFDAY migh tlook like:

```
MEALPLAN
========
mealplan_id (pk)
date
notes
person_id (fk)
mealofday_id (fk)

MEALOFDAY
=========
mealofday_id (pk)
meal_number
meal_description
```

Alternatively, get rid of that `mealofday_id` on `MEALPLAN` and create another table like so:

```
MEALPLAN_MEALOFDAY
=========
mealofday_id (fk/pk)
mealplan_id (fk/pk)
```

Comment: I tried to draw it out but am having issues understanding your idea.  In your recommendation, what exactly is `MEALOFDAY` storing?  Does `MEALOFDAY` only have 2 columns such as `id` and `mealnumber`?   Do all of the other tables remain unchanged (based on scenario one)?

Comment: It's similar to the relationship that MEALPLAN_FOOD has.  It might also have some kind of description ("breakfast").  Otherwise the other tables remain unchanged.

Comment: Each `MEALPLAN_FOOD` record stores each food item and qty.  `MEALOFDAY` stores corresponding records that define the meal number (e.g. meal 1,5).  `MEALPLAN_FOOD` and `MEALOFDAY` will have a one-to-one kind of a relationship.  Two quick clarifying questions: 1. An additional attribute will need to be added to `MEALPLAN` because the current PK will no longer correspond to a mealplan number (each `MEALPLAN` record FKs to each `MEALOFDAY` record), correct?  2. If one mealplan has 6 meals with 5 food items each, then `MEALPLAN`, `MEALPLAN_FOOD`, and `MEALOFDAY` will each have 30 records, correct?

Comment: I was not able to tag you in the previous comment because of the limited number of characters.  Thanks for your help!

Comment: aha, I see!  Replacing that `mealofday_id` with a `MEALPLAN_MEALOFDAY` table will still allow the auto-increment PK of `MEALPLAN` to serve as the meal plan number.  Thanks for the clarification!